# how to make console app from python module

Tags: python, linux, setup.py

I've got a python module with `__main__.py` file and I want to make it an app, which I can call from anywhere.

Something like this:
`$my_app [args]` or `python3 my_app args`
How can I do this?
I suppose, that I need to write something in `setup.py`. Now it looks like this:

```
import vk_mutual_friends_finder
from distutils.core import setup
setup(
    name="vk_mutual_friends_finder",
    packages=["vk_mutual_friends_finder"],
    version="1.0",
    description="""Finds mutual friends in social network
        'vkontakte' (https://vk.com)""",
    author="Stepan Kholodov",
    url="https://github.com/stepuncius/vk_mutual_friends_finder",
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Intended Audience :: Developers and linux power users",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: BSD",
        "Environment :: Console"
        "Operating System :: Linux"
        ],
    )
```

Comment: FWIW if you install a module you can run it as `python3 -m my_app [args]`

Comment: Thank ypu! I've forgotten about it. It's the best way in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to set up an alias (http://www.linfo.org/alias.html).
If you are using bash, you can add the line "alias myapp="python3 /path/to/your/app/myapp.py"" to you ~/.bashrc 
After that you can call your app from everywhere with $myapp args

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to run just `vkmff` instead of `python3 -m vk_mutual_friends_finder` then use `console_scripts` in `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    name="vk_mutual_friends_finder",
    packages=["vk_mutual_friends_finder"],
    ...
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'vkmff=vk_mutual_friends_finder:main',
        ],
    })
```

Also I think you should not `import vk_mutual_friends_finder` in `setup.py`.

Some useful links:

- https://www.pypa.io/en/latest/
- https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject